# Is it possible to modify the Caller ID shown on my phone?

Tags: caller-id, international-prefix

I live in South Korea and receive a lot of calls from overseas.
One thing that bothers me is that because of the local regulations, international caller IDs always contain an international prefix as follows.

From Wikipedia:

> South Korea: 001, 002, 003xx, 005, 006, 007xx, 008

Because of those prefixes, reading call logs is quite unintuitive.

Is there a way to replace those prefixes with a plus sign so that I see nicely formatted numbers like +1 (352) 000-1111 instead of 00213520001111?